# Why do some summons have forehead protector while most of others don't?

Tags: naruto

These are all summons with forehead protector that I can find, it's quite rare among the summons. For example, Sannin's summons, Inuzuka Clan's Ninkens and the Ninnekos don't have forehead protectors.

Are the headbands are overall just for decoration purpose for the summons?

Weren't forehead protectors are worn by most Shinobi since the summons are technically mini ninjas?

**Kakashi's and Guy's summons:**
[image]

**Konohamaru's summons:**
[image]

**Hiruzen's (Third hokage) summons:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forehead Protector in Naruto shows the symbol of Ninja's hidden village and his loyalty towards it.

Similar can be assumed with Summoned animals, Summoned Animals with Summoned animals with  forehead protector seems to be loyal to one village only.

Even [naruto.wikia.com](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique) speculated the same :

> Summons may also wear a forehead protector, suggesting a loyalty to
>   only one village.

Comment: Why others don't wear it? They are loyal to the village.

Comment: @HappyFace They are loyal to summoner not there village.

Comment: Seems reasonable..

Comment: One example are the Toads. Gambabunta is loyal to those who are proven worthy, which is only a rare amount of people I'm sure.  The toads are their own entities, just like the Snakes of Orochimaru, or the Slug of the 5th.  Some of the summons might be passed down from Shinobi of the Fire, but it could be that throughout the ages, certain groups didn't have ties.

Answer (score 1):

Some don't wear a headband as well, because they too large, example being the giant clam that the 2nd mizukage summons. Because the clam is to large it has the villages insignia carved into its shell. Or in an opposite case the animal path pain, several summons being too large and only loyal to pain.